# How do I remove Elder Scroll: Dragon from my inventory?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I recently completed the main storyline. Now that I've used the dragon elder scroll, I don't think I need it. However, the game says it's still a quest item and I can't drop it, stash it in one of my 20 unused storage compartments (thanks, Hearthfire!), or sell it to a vendor (I don't think it has any value, though). I have all 3 DLC add-ons, and I'm assuming that either it's a bug, or it's part of either Dawnguard or a side quest in Dragonborn (I've already killed Miraak).

Comment: It's not a bug, it's intended. Aequitas already gave an answer, personally, i removed it from my inventory and spawned it back into the world so i could decorate my house with it.^^

Answer (score 2):

You can sell it to *Urag gro-Shub* at the College of Winterhold for 2,000 Gold.

---

Alternatively you can use the `RemoveItem` command;

Usage:

```
player.removeitem <ItemID> <#>
```

Description:

```
Remove an item from the inventory.
```

The item id for *Elder Scroll: Dragon* is: `0002D513` or `XX0126DC` in DawnGuard

Comment: isn't there one guy at fort dawnguard who also wants to buy the elder scrolls? or does he only want to buy the elder scroll: sun? not sure...

Comment: @WayneEra, The Moth priest, who resides at whichever castle you've joined forces with, will buy the Sun & Blood scrolls when you're done with the that quest line.  Folks who prematurely sell the Dragon scroll to the Orc Librarian before the end of the Dawngard quest-line will find they need to purchase it back for a significant markup.